# Passport Facebook strategy returns undefined values

Tags: passport-facebook

I am using the passport-facebook plugin in a NextJS app and my test script defines the strategy as below:

```
// Configure Passport
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
  callbackURL: process.env.FACEBOOK_APP_CALLBACK,
},
  function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(profile);
  }
));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

My authentication routes are:

```
// Facebook
router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));
router.get('/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    successRedirect: '/success',
    failureRedirect: '/failure',
  }),
);
```

All I'm trying to do with this for now, is to display all the values returned by Facebook upon a successful authentication. The authentication works as expected but Facebook seems to be returning `undefined` for most keys in the `profile` object:

```
{ id: '1234567812345677',
  username: undefined,
  displayName: 'John Doe',
  name:
   { familyName: undefined,
     givenName: undefined,
     middleName: undefined },
  gender: undefined,
  profileUrl: undefined,
  provider: 'facebook',
  _raw: '{"name":"John Doe","id":"1234567812345677"}',
  _json: { name: 'John Doe', id: '1234567812345677' } }
```

All I get is the `displayName` and `id`; everything else is `undefined`. What's going wrong? A very similar question was asked here before but none of the answers (no accepted answer) offered address the problem.

Comment: Complete guess- check your application scopes. You probably don't have permission for full profile information.

Comment: I haven't specified any explicit `scope` to my authentication call. Shouldn't something like *username* be available as a part of the default scope? All the tutorials I've come across online (including PassportJS documentation) instruct you to specify a scope should you need any additional access, such as timeline, etc.

Comment: do you found a solution please ? I got the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience in this area, but from looking at the [readme](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) of facebook-passport, it sounds like you need to use the `profileFields` in your `FacebookStrategy`. :

> The Facebook profile contains a lot of information about a user. **By
>   default, not all the fields in a profile are returned**. The fields
>   needed by an application can be indicated by setting the profileFields
>   option.
>
> ```
> new FacebookStrategy({
>   clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
>   clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
>   callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
>   profileFields: ['id', 'displayName', 'photos', 'email']
> }), ...)
> ```
>
> Refer to the User section of the Graph API Reference for the complete
>   set of available fields.

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work. Throws an error:

Error
    at /home/ubuntu/nano/node_modules/passport-facebook/lib/strategy.js:165:21
    at passBackControl (/home/ubuntu/nano/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nano/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1047:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)